# Rails Tutorial 5.3.0 TDD Error: "undefined method 'visit'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, nomethoderror

Following the Hartl Tutorial online and can't seem to find a solution to Chapter 5 section 3.0. At this point of the tutorial, I seems that I am supposed to make my rspec code more concise by defining a full_title in "spec/support/utilities.rb" then editing the "spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb" file.

Here is my "spec/support/utilities.rb":

```
def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
end
```

and my "spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb":

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

subject { page }

  describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }

    it { should have_content('Sample App') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('')) }
    it { should_not have_title('| Home') }
  end

  describe "Help page" do
    before { vist root_path }

    it { should have_content('Help') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Help')) }
  end

  describe "About page" do
    before { visit root_path}

    it { should have_content('About') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('About')) }
  end

  describe "Contact page" do
    before { visit contact_path }

    it { should have_content('Contact') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Contact')) }
  end
end
```

and my "spec_helper.rb":

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'capybara/rspec'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  # Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
  # If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # ## Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr

    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
    # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
    # the seed, which is printed after each run.
    #     --seed 1234
    config.order = "random"
    config.include Capybara::DSL
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end
```

When I run:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

I get:

```
Failures:

  1) Static pages About page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(full_title('About')) }
       expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Static pages Help page 
     Failure/Error: before { vist root_path }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `vist' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007fe53b33f338>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Static pages Help page 
     Failure/Error: before { vist root_path }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `vist' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007fe53b44d8b0>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.28441 seconds
9 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:26 # Static pages About page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:18 # Static pages Help page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19 # Static pages Help page
```

I've seen on other posts that this error may be due to a lack of "Capybara" because "visit" is a Capybara method. I checked my Gem file and it shows Capybara:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  # The following optional lines are part of the advanced setup.
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', github: 'sporkrb/spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
  # gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.
  # gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  # gem 'win32console', '1.3.2'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I'm not sure what is needed to make `visit` a valid method for the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually misspelled the word visit:

`before { vist root_path }`

And for the test to pass, you need to change the path of the *About* and *Help* tests to their respective paths.

For example, you are testing the *Help page* but instead of visiting the `help_path`, you are visiting the `root_path`

```
describe "Help page" do
  before { visit root_path }
```

Same goes for the `About page`.

Comment: Thanks! I corrected "visit" under "describe "Help page" do". However, I'm not sure what you mean by changing the path of _About_ and _Help_ tests to their respective paths. Sorry, I'm very new to programming.

Comment: Ah I get it now. I will make changes as soon as possible and let you know what happens. Thanks!

Comment: It works! I can confirm the answer provided is a successful solution.

Answer (score 0):

i have same situation but my path's is okey and tests are failed

**"spec/support/utilities.rb"**

```
def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "agroBox App"
    if page_title.empty?
        base_title
    else
        "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
end
```

**"spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb"**

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Static pages" do
  subject { page }
  describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }
    it { should have_content('agroBox App') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('')) }
    it { should_not have_title('| Home') }
  end
  describe "Help page" do
    before { visit help_path }
    it { should have_content('Help') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Help')) }
  end
  describe "About page" do
    before { visit about_path }
    it { should have_content('About') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('About Us')) }
  end
  describe "Contact page" do
    before { visit contact_path }
    it { should have_content('Contact') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Contact')) }
  end
end
```

**"spec_helper.rb"**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
  # Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
  # If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    # ## Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr
    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
    # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
    # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
    # the seed, which is printed after each run.
    #     --seed 1234
    config.order = "random"
    config.include Capybara::DSL
  end
end
Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
end
```

`$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`

```
Failures:
  1) Static pages About page should have title "agroBox App | About Us"
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(full_title('About Us')) }
       expected #has_title?("agroBox App | About Us") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  2) Static pages Contact page should have title "agroBox App | Contact"
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(full_title('Contact')) }
       expected #has_title?("agroBox App | Contact") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  3) Static pages Help page should have title "agroBox App | Help"
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(full_title('Help')) }
       expected #has_title?("agroBox App | Help") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Maybe it helps someone all this errors about Capybara 2.x, just a change like in lines  with asterisks and your tests will pass ;)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }

    it { should have_content('some App') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('')) }
    it { should_not have_title('| Home') }
  end

  describe "Help page" do
    before { visit help_path }


**it { page.should have_content('Help') } 
    it { page.has_title?(full_title('Help')) }**
  end

  describe "About page" do
    before { visit about_path }

    **it { page.should have_content('About') }
    it { page.has_title?(full_title('About Us')) }**
  end

  describe "Contact page" do
    before { visit contact_path }

    **it { page.should have_content('Contact') }
    it { page.has_title?(full_title('Contact')) }**
  end
end
```